# An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited

Tags: ios, xcode

Во время добавления элементов интерфейса в `main.storyboard` в частности    элемента `label` возникает ошибка:

> An internal error occurred. Editing functionality may be limited.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В частности выглядит так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После запуска на симуляторе просто белый экран, а потом происходит вылет программы, все возвращается на экран выбора программ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять в чем проблема!

Answer (score 0):

Это баг Xcode. Если после перезапуска проблема повторяется, можно почистить папку Derived Data. Перейдите в Preferences -> Locations и нажмите на маленькую стрелку рядом с адресом папки Derived Data. Затем закройте Xcode и удалите всю папку Derived Data.

Comment: Удалил папку вроде проблема пропала, но потом сообщение появилось снова. И также приложение при запуске в симуляторе просто показывает белый экран, потом закрывается.

Comment: Может из-за того, что переустанавливал Xcode возникла проблема, раньше просто такого не было. Может дело ещё в моих системных параметрах!

Comment: Как закроется, в консоль пишет чего-нибудь? Сам Xcode не падает? Какая его версия? Системные параметры не должны влиять, если вы серьёзно не модифицировали ~/Library или другие системные папки

Comment: Извините, что не сразу ответил, так как был занят. Ничего в консоль не пишет, к сожалению! Сам Xcode не падает, версия - 9.4.1(9F2000)

Comment: Все же похоже на какой-то внутренний баг. А какой компьютер и версия системы?

Comment: Mac book pro (Early 2011) Mac OS High Sierra - 10.13.6

Comment: ну что, нет ни у кого никаких мыслей по этому поводу??